# Why does my gradle sub-project not configure as a sub-project when the sub-project is the current directory?

Tags: gradle

I just figured this out, so I'm sharing.

I have a gradle project (mama), and several sub-projects ("akira", "chris" , "maria", and "bo" ). If the current directory is mama, everything behaves as 
expected, and as documented in [The gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:depending_on_output_of_another_project).

```
------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                            
Root project                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                            

Root project mama
+--- Project ':akira’
+--- Project ':bo’
+--- Project ':chris’
\--- Project ':maria’
```

However, whenever I navigate to a child directory, gradle always configures it as a root project, and all cross-project configuration fails.

Why does this happen, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by sub-projects having a "settings.gradle" file in the sub-project's directory. If this file exists in the current directory, gradle configures it as a root project.

To fix the problem, move any contents of each sub-project's "settings.gradle" file into where-ever else is appropriate, and delete the file. Sub-projects do not need to define rootProject, nor include anything.

This behavior is described in the user-guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:initialization).